# Is there a name for this encoding? (bits represent division by 2 from most to least significant)

Tags: math, encoding, floating-point

I'm working on a specification which requires a fractional number to be expressed (the sub-second portion of a timestamp) in a way that can be encoded with a certain precision (number of bits) and then decoded using the leading bits to get approximately the same fraction back.

The purpose is to allow different systems to support different timestamp precisions.  Some systems may only have millisecond-precision for timestamps, others may have nanosecond precision or more.  Plus, additional random data is stored after this value and due to space constraints, there is no way for the parser to know the exact delineation in all cases of how many bits are sub-second precision vs random data.  The parsing should still be able to function properly and get a timestamp that is "as precise as possible".

The encoding is inspired by what is done for IEEE 754 floating point numbers and would basically treat each successive bit as representing if the next section is above or below the value divided by two.  So given one bit, the possible values are 0 = .0 and 1 = .5.  With two bits, the combinations are 00 = 0.0, 01 = .25, 10 = .5, 11 = .75.  And so on.

My question is: what is this called?  I feel like there must be some prior art on this that I'm not aware of which I can refer to when describing this encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just standard place notation.

Place notation in base **b** essentially works like this: you have a "decimal" point (which in this case is not really decimal because "decimal" means "ten"). The place directly left of the decimal point has the value **p<sub>0</sub> × b<sup>0</sup>** where p<sub>0</sub> is the value written into place 0. The place to the left of that has the value **p<sub>1</sub> × b<sup>1</sup>** and then next has **p<sub>2</sub> × b<sup>2</sup>**, and so on; place n has the value **p<sub>n</sub> × b<sup>n</sup>**.

Likewise, directly to the *right* of the point, you have **p<sub>-1</sub> × b<sup>-1</sup>** and then **p<sub>-2</sub> × b<sup>-2</sup>**, and so on; place -n has the value **p<sub>-n</sub> × b<sup>-n</sup>**.

Or in other words: place notation works exactly the same on both sides of the point.

And the total value of the number is simply the sum of the values of all places.

For example, in base-10 (i.e. **b = 10**), it looks like this:

```
123.45
```

is

1. 3 × 10<sup>0</sup> = 3 × 1 = 3 +
2. 2 × 10<sup>1</sup> = 2 × 10 = 20 +
3. 1 × 10<sup>2</sup> = 1 × 10 × 10 = 1 × 100 = 100 +
4. 4 × 10<sup>-1</sup> = 4 × <sup>1</sup>∕<sub>10</sub> = <sup>4</sup>∕<sub>10</sub> +
5. 5 × 10<sup>-2</sup> = 5 × <sup>1</sup>∕<sub>10</sub> × <sup>1</sup>∕<sub>10</sub> = 5 × <sup>1</sup>∕<sub>100</sub> = <sup>5</sup>∕<sub>100</sub>
6. = 3 + 20 + 100 + <sup>4</sup>∕<sub>10</sub> + <sup>5</sup>∕<sub>100</sub> = 3 + 20 + 100 + .4 + .05 = 123.45

[All digits are assumed to be in base-10.]

That is how place notation works, and you have exactly the same thing but with **b = 2**.

In other words, your representation is literally just "writing down the number in binary". More precisely, writing down the fractional part with an implicit `0.` at the beginning.

Comment: Interesting.  You're right, it's the exact same thing as "the numbers after the decimal point (fractional part), but written in binary (base 2)". Thanks.